# Why this program is giving only first two words as output? what data is stored in s1[]?

Tags: java, string

I was trying to use the split() function but I don't know how data is stored in a string(precisely s1[] in the code below) and while displaying it using for loop it gives the output as 'hello java'. Please help me understand the structure for how data is stored in s1[] after using split() function and why this code is displaying the mentioned output!

```
String s="hello java world";  
String s1[]*=s.split("\\s");  
for(int i=0;i<s1.length-1;i++)  
    {  
    System.out.print(s1[i]);  
    }  
Output:  
hello  
java
```

Comment: `i<s1.length-1` will skip the last one. Change to `i<s1.length`.

Comment: `String s1[]*=s.split("\\s");  ` won't compile.

Comment: "`for(int i=0;i<s1.length-1;i++)  `" what do you think the `-1` does here?

Comment: Also, the output from this code (after fixing the errant `*`) would be [`hellojava`](https://ideone.com/Fbocw8).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the errant `*`, the issue is in the `for` loop condition. After, splitting the string, `s1.length == 3` and the valid indexes are `0,1,2`. So your loop only iterates through `i==0` and `i==1`. When `i==2`, the condition `i < s1.length-1` is false.

Just get rid of the `-1`

```
String s = "hello java world";
String[] s1 = s.split("\\s");
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {  
    System.out.println(s1[i]);  
}
```

I've added spaces to make more legible. Also moved the `[]` in the array declaration as (from what I've read) this is the preferred location. And changed `print` to `println` to print each word on its own line.

Comment: `String[]` is preferred, no space. ([Numerous examples here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html)).

Comment: @AndyTurner Ok. Updated.